# Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame when date is on the x axis and states

Tags: r, economics

Edited:
Example:

```
FIPS       Date     Counts 
1001       Jan_22    0
1003       Jan_22    1
1004       Jan_22    0
1001       Jan_23    1
1003       Jan_23    5
1004       Jan_23    0
1001       Jan_24    6
1003       Jan_24    10
1004       Jan_24    1 
1001       Jan_25    8
1003       Jan_25    12
1004       Jan_25    3

Result:
    FIPS   Date     Counts
    1001   Jan_23   1
    1003   Jan_22   1
    1004   Jan_24   1
```

I am trying to find the number of days since the 1st case of Covid-19 within different counties in the United States. I need to find the first occurrence of 1 case confirmed in that county and then get R to tell me for each FIPS code is on which date was it that there the first day it was confirmed for 1 case. I am doing all 3141 counties. The dates go from Jan_22 to April_30.

Edit3:
And the number of observations is 314200, with 3 variables.

```
t.first <- data_long[match(unique(data_long$Counts, data_long$Counts))]`
```

I want to use t.first to try to get the first occurrence in that data.

Comment: Based on your description, i feel `slice_head` function may be helpful after arranging the data

Comment: Ronak Shah Thank you for the reminder, I just changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep rows where `Counts > 0` and then for each `FIPS` select the 1st row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Counts > 0) %>%
  group_by(FIPS) %>%
  slice(1L)

#   FIPS Date   Counts
#  <int> <chr>   <int>
#1  1001 Jan_23      1
#2  1003 Jan_22      1
#3  1004 Jan_24      1
```

Comment: What is the 1L part of the slice function - why not just slice(1)?

Comment: It is the same thing. `1L` is integer, `1` is numeric.

Comment: If I were using a large data set where the data set is called "data_long", where would I insert this to get all the first occurrence of 1 in that data set.

Comment: If you have  same columns and column names in `df_long` use `df_long` instead of `df`.

Comment: Yep it works, but I had 3142 observations before now I only have 2844 observations, does this code clear out some N/A data?

Comment: It keeps only 1st row for each `FIPS`. In the example you have shared see how 12 rows of data is collapsed into only 3 rows. Same happens with `df_long`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
subset(df1[df1$Counts >0,], !duplicated(FIPS))
#  FIPS   Date Counts
#2 1003 Jan_22      1
#4 1001 Jan_23      1
#9 1004 Jan_24      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(FIPS = c(1001L, 1003L, 1004L, 1001L, 1003L, 1004L, 
1001L, 1003L, 1004L, 1001L, 1003L, 1004L), Date = c("Jan_22", 
"Jan_22", "Jan_22", "Jan_23", "Jan_23", "Jan_23", "Jan_24", "Jan_24", 
"Jan_24", "Jan_25", "Jan_25", "Jan_25"), Counts = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 8L, 12L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```